# Exception Value: local variable 'other_user' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

So, this is probably just something simple I'm doing wrong here. But basically, I am attempting to simply pass in the pk of the other_user. I tested that the query works correctly, and am indeed printing the other user. Just don't know where to place it correctly in my code so I can pass it to the render part.

**local variable 'other_user' referenced before assignment**

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
    if not username:
        raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
    if not description:
        raise ValueError("You must write a description")
    if not photo:
        raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

    user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username, 
            description= description,
            photo= photo,

        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user 


def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
    user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
            description=description,
            photo=photo,

        )

    user.is_admin=True
    user.is_staff=True
    user.is_superuser=True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

class Meta:
    swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
#what I added
description                 = models.TextField()
photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


objects = ProfileManager()


def __str__(self):
    return self.username


def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin


def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
    return True



class Conversation(models.Model):
members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class UserVote(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))







class InstantMessage(models.Model):


sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data creation",default=timezone.now(), null=False)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.message

#tests to see if messages are exclusive between sender, receiver (won't work with new model)
@classmethod
def find_messages_exclusive_to_profile(cls,sender,receiver):
    #members = receiver AND sender, not receiver or sender 
    exclusive_conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members= receiver ).filter(members= sender)


    exclusive_messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(conversation__in=exclusive_conversations)

    return exclusive_messages




def message (request, profile_id):



if request.method == 'POST':




    form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('dating_app:messages', other_user.id)
else:

    conversation, created = Conversation.objects.filter(members = request.user).filter(members= profile_id).get_or_create()
    print(conversation)
    other_user = conversation.members.filter(id=profile_id).get()
    print(other_user)

    form = MessageForm({'sender': request.user, 'conversation': conversation})

    context = {'form' : form }

    return render(request, 'dating_app/message.html', context)
```

Comment: Is this a ModelForm?

Comment: Yes it is a model form

Comment: Why are you filtering twice on key `members`?

Comment: it's like an AND ... get me request.user AND other_user.

Comment: So isnt your `other_user.id` and `profile_id` supposed to be same?

Comment: yeah but they aren't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212508/discussion-between-mohitc-and-rez).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the ModelForm's instance from `form.instance` and get value from there.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    m = form.instance
    return redirect('dating_app:messages', m.id)
```

You are mostly likely to also get the instance while saving it as

`m = form.save()`

Comment: profile_id doesn't work and takes me to my request.user's page and passed the request.user pk

Comment: I need to pass my other users pk

Comment: how can I define it in my if statement without returning 2 of the same objects?

Comment: there ok I did it

Comment: Updated answer, try now

Comment: not working, returning my instant_message object pk of 66, not my other_users pk which is 2